# erlang: how do I end processes on my system?

Tags: process, erlang, terminate

I ran the command `i().` in the werl shell and it outputs a list of processes currently running on my system. Is there some way to end them all with one command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processes what you see after `i().` command are all processes including ones essential for VM itself. You should not stop them all except you are going to stop whole VM. Your own processes you have to clean up yourself. Recommended way for serious applications is following OTP principles.

There are two main ways how to stop VM. First one is graceful shutdown which you invoke using shell command `q().` which is exactly same as `init:stop().` It's take a while but you should use this way for real systems running serious applications.

The second way you can use for VM nodes where you are experimenting or for temporary nodes which you use for connecting to application nodes. It is immediately stop of VM using `erlang:halt().` There are faster ways how invoke this VM halting using `Ctrl+C` then `a` and `Enter` or `Ctrl+G` then `q` and `Enter`.

You can use `erlang:halt/0` or `init:stop/0` from your script or for remote invocation.

Comment: I pressed `CTRL+C` and nothing happened, is it maybe `CTRL+G` then `a` and `enter`? I also tried `erlang:halt().` which exited the system but the processes did not end when I restarted and typed `i().`

Comment: No, `Ctrl+G` do something different but you can use `Ctrl+G` then `q` and `Enter`. `Ctrl+G` is far more powerful. Try `h` for help.

Comment: Oh, you also tried `erlang:halt().` which exited the system but the processes did not end? How it happen? Are they running nowhere? Sorry, you missed something essential here.

Comment: I'm not sure if they are running. Some of them are three days old and I just noticed they exist after `i().` ran? I have no idea how to fix this problem...

Comment: I have just started system and tried `i()`. I see your processes there too. I'm doomed. Sorry, I can't resist. I will try not making fun of you. When you end VM using erlang:halt() or other way all processes inside VM ends. Processes what you see after start of VM are essential to running system and you should not try kill them (for example by [exit(X, kill) || X <- erlang:processes()] but it doesn't even work because you will shoot yourself first). If you left your own processes your own program is responsible for clean up.